# Navigation controllers within navigation controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

I have a view controller (vc1) that contains a container view (I'm using storyboards).

Within that container view is a navigation controller and a root view controller (vc2).

Root view controller in turn has two buttons so that they both segue to two other view controllers.

All of these happen within the same view controller vc1.

From within either of those view controllers how do I access vc1?

Baring in mind that I'm using storyboards.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: That is because i need a animating background which i don't wanna break.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your storyboard